# Merge [DMX] and [DMX512] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are currently two different tags that refer to the exact same technology.

[dmx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dmx) - 37 questions

[dmx512](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dmx512) - 8 questions

Both tags also have the same description:

> DMX512 (Digital MultipleX) is a standard for digital communication
>   networks that are commonly used to control stage lighting and effects.

Although there is no official variant of DMX512-A *(E1.11 - 2008, USITT DMX512-A)* it would make sense to merge any questions from `[dmx512]` to the more general `[dmx]` tag and remove the `[dmx512]` tag to avoid fragmented questions across both tags and the need for users to include both tags in their question.

It would be simple to manually edit the 8 questions in `[dmx512]` but i furged this is a question for the meta.

Thanks.

Comment: Having been through all of the questions now it might make more sense to keep `[dmx512]` for the lighting protocol and use `[dmx]` for Data Mining Expressions (the MSQL protocol) edit: Disregard `[dmx-ssas]` exists. it just seems the auto tagger is mis tagging.

Comment: I couldn't find any data mining questions like you refer to.  So I think we don't need to consider that until it shows up.  DMX512 seems to be the base name for that technology, so I say we merge everything to that.  Let DMX die, it can come back later if it is needed.

Comment: DMX512 is called DMX colloquially, but either tag would work. I guess my only question is if someone creates a new question about DMX would both tags be suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have merged all the DMX questions into [dmx512](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dmx512).  All but one were about that standard.  There was one question about data mining and it turns out we already have a tag, [dmx-ssas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dmx-ssas).

Comment: Thanks, I will add the [dmx-ssas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dmx-ssas) tags back to the questions I removed `[dmx]` from